# Regular Expression for dd/MM/yyy or dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: .net, regex

I'll admit I'm rubbish at regular expressions and find some of the tools out there that are supposed to make generating them easier painfully difficult to use. That's my fault granted.. anyway..

Can anyone come up with a single regular expression that will allow both
dd/MM/yyyy and/or dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Yes, I've Googled for it and searched regexlib.

It would be much appreciated.

Cheers in advance.

**UPDATE :**

Guys, I obviously considered server side parsing.. I am asking specifically for a regex.
I may still fall back on this.

I have also looked at lots of online material including sites that a quick Google brings up, so please don't submit obvious sites as i've tried them and resorted to asking the question here.

**UPDATE :**

Guys, I'm leaning towards doing it via server side date parsing.. But I would still be curious what the regex would be.

Comment: Since you tagged this question as ".net", DateTime.TryParse (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx) might be a useful alternative (depending on what you are trying to do).

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: You're probably right Jason. I'm still curious how it could be done with regex though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably better off using `DateTime.TryParseExact()` for this.  It has an overload that allows you to specify multiple possible formats.

Comment: I may resort to this but am curious to find a regex solution.

Comment: This is correct. Unless you resort to an absurd regex that is difficult to maintain, your regex will parse `31/02/2009` while `DateTime.TryParseExact` will not. And then add a more tricky example like `29/02/1900` versus `29/02/2000` and you'll realize you should just let `DateTime.TryParseExact` do the hard work for you.

Comment: Even though this doesn't answer the regex question, it is the correct way of validating the dates in the 2 formats I require. Hence why I have marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one

```
[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}( [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})?
```

Edit: improved formatting, thanks Nathan Campos.

Or, eliminating many more invalid values:

```
[0-3][0-9]/[01][0-9]/[0-2][0-9]{3}( [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?
```

Comment: Shouldn't the space be represented by \s as in
[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}(\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})?

Comment: Not quite. as this allows 99/12/2009 12:00:03. Can we limit it to valid days and months

Comment: Lee, regex are really a good tool to use to parse text but using it to parse valid dates and times is going to drive you nuts. The regular expression will be kilometres long to make sure you have all cases correct. As Joel has already pointed out, `DateTime.TryParseExact()` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the different suggestions here: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, and does most validation (except for number of days in months):

```
([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/[0-9]{4}( ([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){2})?
```

You could add month-wise intelligence to the days, but the RegEx expression for that would look rather hairy.

Comment: hmm. This seems to allow : 12/12/2009 42:00:00

Comment: Nope.  See ([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]).  The first option is 0 or 1, followed by 0-9.  The second option is 2, followed by 0-3.  BTW, I'm using <a href="http://www.regexbuddy.com>RegexBuddy</a> to help me through this stuff.  I highly recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-]?(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-]?(18|19|20|21)\\d{2} ([0-2][0-4]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])$
```

Valid data format is 25-03-2014 24:10:10
if you need to validate for 25/03/2014 24:10:10 use this

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/]?(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[/]?(18|19|20|21)\\d{2} ([0-2][0-4]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])$
```

Answer (score 0):

Reg Ex:

^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}( [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} (A|P|a|p)(M|m))?$

E.g.

5/31/2016 12:00:00 PM

5/31/2016

5/3/2016

05/3/2016 12:00:00 PM

5/3/2016 12:00:00 PM

5/3/2016 12:00:00 AM